# Optimal transport: find cost function given observed transport

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, optimal-transportation, inverse-problems

Could you advise me please on what to read on the "inverse" problem: suppose I have a source measure, a target measure and I observe the solution to optimal transport problem -- can I "back out" the cost function e.g. find a cost function such that the observed transport is optimal conditional on this cost function?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, one probably needs further regularity requirements on the cost function, otherwise $c(x,y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in spt(\pi)$ and $c(x,y)=+\infty$ otherwise trivially does the job ($\pi$ being the transference plan)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I agree that the space of functions should be restricted (and may be with very stringent requirements to get uniqueness). I am looking for a systematic study of this.

Comment: Even with regularity enforced you should not expect uniqueness, at least not for a single "observation". For, you can always add a (smooth) non-negative function vanishing on $spt(\pi)$, at least when this support is smooth. So I guess it's more about requiring "structure", really (e.g. strict convexity, twist conditions, etc...) I'm sorry I can't help you more, I've never heard of such a problem.

Comment: To add another complication, in one dimension for any cost of the form $c(x,y)=h(x-y)$ for $h$ convex, the solution to optimal transport will be the identical, and is given by the so-called monotone map.

Comment: By Lagrange multipliers, such cost functions have the form $C(x,y) =a(x) +b(y)+ c(x,y)$ where $c$ is nonnegative everywhere and $0$ on the support of the transport map. If you're asking for functions that satisfy linear conditions and inequalities such as being a metric, or strict convexity as suggested by Leo, then finding a suitable cost function is a linear programming problem.

Comment: If both functions are supported on a finite space, and you demand that the cost function be a metric, it should suffice that the transport map has no loops where $A$ is sent to $B$, $B$ is sent to $C$, and $C$ is sent to $A$, or whatever. Indeed, in this case, the transport map induced a partial order, which you can complete to a total order, and then take the cost to be the number of steps in the total order

Comment: @Gabe K: good point!

Comment: It is strange question, for if the $c$-optimal coupling $\pi$ is observable, then are the dual Kantorovich potentials $-\phi=\psi^c$, $\psi^{cc}=\psi$ also observable? For we have always $-\phi(x)+\psi(y)\leq c(x,y)$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ with equality iff $x\in \partial^c \psi(y)$ iff $y\in \partial^c \phi(x)$ iff $(x,y)\in spt(\pi)$. Therefore if $\phi, \psi$ are observable, then you have pointwise lower bound for $c(x,y)$, namely $-\phi(x)+\psi(y)$ for arbitrary $x,y$. All the above answers show the problem is  underdetermined, with many arbitrary parameters.

Comment: Look again at the inequality $-\phi(x)+\psi(y)\leq c(x,y)$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$. If $h(x,y)$ is any function satisfying $-\phi(x)+\psi(y)\leq c(x,y)+h(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ and obtains equality iff $(x,y)\in spt(\pi)$, then the new cost $c':=c+h$ will again have $\pi$ as $c'$-optimal transport (... if i'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

See "Inverse Optimal Transport" By Stuart and Wolfram, SIAM J. App. Math, 80(1), 2020, and "[Learning to Match via Inverse Optimal Transport](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03644)" by Li et al., JMLR 2019.